# Understanding the JMS communication schema by example

Tags: java, jms

Going through the `JMS` Oracle [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncdx.html), I faced the following schema:

[image]

There was also metnioned that the JMS application basically composed of the parts:

- JMS provider
- JMS clients
- Messages
- Administered objects

I'd like to understand that communication schema by a concrete example. Assume that we have two web applications running on `Tomcat` and `ApacheMQ` as a message broker. Which is what in that example?

It's clear that the web-aplications are `JMS-client`s, `ApacheMQ` seems to be a `JMS-provider`. Messages sending between the clients through the JMS-provider for interacting with each other are `Messages`.

But what the administrative tools are then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Administered objects are also park of web application. You use them to obtain connection (from ConnectionFactory) to JMS provider. You sent message to JMS provider and it routes it to right destination (Destination - topic or queue).

Comment: So, the administrated objects provide the implemntation of the `Connection` interface through the `JNDI`-name in order to decouple code from unnecesary dependencies to vendor-specifiec `ConnectionFactory`. Do I understand you correctly?

Comment: Yes, you will read about it later.
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnceh.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnceh.html#bncej